# Beamer stop working with updated MikTex

Tags: beamer, miktex2.9

Beamer was working in my windows 10 before MikTex (version 2.9) update. Now, it has stopped working, showing-

File error 'enumerate.sty not found'.

Could someone help me fix, please.

Comment: @Zarko Sorry! I couldn't get it. Would you please elaborate. Thank you

Comment: If you have a multi-user MikTeX installation, make sure you update in both Admin and User mode. (Contrary to what one might think, Admin mode is not 'stronger' than user mode. In fact user-installed packages take precedence. So you need to update as admin and user.) If that is done (or you have a single-user install without admin mode) go to the MikTeX Console and click "Tasks > Refresh file name database" (do this in admin and user mode if possible). If that does not help, try "Tasks > Update package database" as well.

Comment: @moewe thanks a lot. It's working now. I think this could be posted as an answer instead of comment

Comment: What would say about marking this a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864?

Comment: @moewe Well. This seems to be the original answer

Comment: @moewe This part answers my question "Synchronization of the repositories can now be done through the tasks menu with the entry tasks->Update package database.

The FNDB can be updated with tasks-> Refresh file name database".   But it will not be easy to locate the answer for the users like me.

Comment: @Zarko the one in latex-dev/tools would only be used by the test releases accessed with commands such as  pdflatex-dev, the standard latex commands such as pdflatex will use the one from tex\latex\tools

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank you very much for info.  I wasn't aware for this. I will delete my comment.